# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Application' not found

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to create a simple CLI app with PHP but I keep getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Application' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newcli/dan.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newcli/dan.php on line 6

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Application' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newcli/dan.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newcli/dan.php on line 6
```

What am I doing wrong? My PHP version: `PHP 7.1.0RC6 (cli) (built: Nov  9 2016 04:45:59) ( NTS )`

dan.php:

```
#! usr/bin/env php
<?php use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Application('Task App', '1.0');

$app->add(new Acme\ShowCommand());
$app->run();
```

Comment: are you sure that the console component is installed correctly ? whats the output of `php composer.phar info` from the directly where the projects files are ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `use` statement must be placed after the `require 'vendor/autoload.php'`

```
#! usr/bin/env php
<?php 

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$app = new Application('Task App', '1.0');

$app->add(new Acme\ShowCommand());
$app->run();
```

Answer (score -1):

Some classes can be absent in your `vendor`. So, it can be resolved by a `composer install`.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The other answer, which got accepted by the OP, indicates that moving a line around helped. Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Yes. But, indeed, in this case, to place the `use` statement  after the require `vendor/autoload.php` is the good answer. But, this php fatal error can be displayed too, if your vendor are not completly installed.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it